# How to import a file into another file?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to import a file (model.ipynb), which is a sub folder, into another file (test.ipynb) but am getting an:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.model'
```

[The folder setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGmmr.png)
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7VJ6.png)

I am not sure why it is not working as all the file names match.

Comment: `from .utils import model`?

Comment: If the model file is an ipython notebook file, I think you'll need to do something more sophisticated to import from it, as described in https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/4.x/examples/Notebook/rstversions/Importing%20Notebooks.html

Comment: There does seem to be a package to help with this https://pypi.org/project/import-ipynb/

Comment: Thanks guys, yes it seems to be a bit more complicated then I thought. Will be changing the files to py which solves the issue.